# How to polyfill DOMParser on Web Worker to be used by AWS S3 SDK upload?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web-worker, polyfills

We are using the AWS S3 SDK to upload files from browser to S3 buckets. As the amount and size of files can be huge and impact the UI rendering and interactions, we decided to pull the upload process into a Web Worker thread. This way the user is free to navigate and interact on our single page application.

When we upload a small files, everything runs well. The issue is when S3 SDK tries to upload a big file. It splits the file in several chunks and uploads each chunk individualy. The s3 server returns an XML response and the S3 SDK tries to parse it using the DOMParser class, wich is not defined in the Web Worker scope.

Is there a way the DOMParser can be polyfilled in order to make S3 SKD perform the upload on Web Worker?

Answer (score 3):

Because of some versioning issue jsdom didn't worked for me. But i was able to polyfill DOMParser for aws sdk by using following code.

```
var DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;
window.DOMParser = DOMParser;
```

Ran browserify and created domparser.js

```
browserify main.js -o domparser.js
```

Then Imported domparser.js before importing aws sdk

```
importScripts('domparser.js');
importScripts('https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.176.0.js');
```

Answer (score 2):

Answering my on question:

I was able to polyfill DOMParser on web worker using [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) and [browserify](http://browserify.org/)

jsdom simulates a window enviroment, and browserify bundles jsdom to be executed on browser (jsdom was intended to run on nodejs)

It worked pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

In 2022 you can also polyfill DOMParser for the AWS sdk using [linkedom](https://github.com/WebReflection/linkedom) instead of JSDOM. This results in a much smaller bundle (~300kb instead of 3mb in my experience).

Code looks like this...

```
const linkedom = require('linkedom')
const { DOMParser } = linkedom
window.DOMParser = DOMParser
```

As with the other answers you can use browserify to produce a bundle.

```
browserify index.js -o domparser.js
```

Then just import that bundle into your web worker before the AWS sdk.

```
importScripts('domparser.js');
```